# AWS boto sqs - why can't I post messages bigger than 196 000 bytes?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-sqs

According to the [SQS docs](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/#Can_I_configure_the_maximum_payload_size_my_queues_will_accept), it it possible to post messages up to 256KB of data. I configured my queue to 256KB of data, but when I post using boto, I max out at ~196 000 bytes. Anything over this, I get the following response from SQS :

```
boto.exception.SQSError: SQSError: 400 Bad Request
<?xml version="1.0"?><ErrorResponse xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/">
<Error><Type>Sender</Type><Code>InvalidParameterValue</Code><Message>
Value for parameter       MessageBody is invalid. Reason: Message body must be shorter     than 262144 bytes.</Message>
<Detail/></Error><RequestId>dd24151b-d499-5bb1-acd0-5f776011e960</RequestId></ErrorResponse>
```

Small python program to illustrate :

```
from boto.sqs.message import Message
from boto.sqs.connection import SQSConnection
from boto.sqs.message import Message
import sys

sqs_conn = SQSConnection(AWS_KEY, AWS_SECRET)

data = mylong_256kb_string

print sys.getsizeof(data)
current_queue = sqs_conn.create_queue('test_temp_queue')

m = Message()
m.set_body(data)

current_queue.write(m)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because by default, boto base64-encodes the payload of a message before sending it and decodes it upon reading.  This is mainly because of historical reasons; in the early days of SQS there were a lot of restrictions on what kinds of characters could be in an SQS message.  That's not really the case anymore so the encode/decode probably isn't necessary.

To get around it, just use `boto.message.RawMessage` class rather than `boto.message.Message`.